# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring gateway `implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"` as my project gateway, define the filter in application.properties like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory
```

And my gateway filter code look like this:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory implements GatewayFilter {

    @Value("${dolphin.gateway.jwt.verify:true}")
    private boolean jwtVerfiy;

    final static List<String> apiEndpoints = List.of("/register", "/login");

    final static Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isApiSecured = r -> apiEndpoints.stream()
            .noneMatch(uri -> r.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

when I start the project, the log output shows error like this:

```
   021-09-19 22:51:42.480 ERROR 1 --- [oundedElastic-7] r.c.s.Schedulers                         : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:187) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:228) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator$$Lambda$924/0x0000000069f16e40.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:481) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:414) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:425) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:297) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:563) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
```

I have tried to tweak the filter name with `JwtAuthenticationFilterGatewayFilterFactory` and `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, both throw the same error. where am I going wrong? what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: your `@Component` is not picked up. why? it is impossible to say with whatever you have provided in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if implement `GatewayFilter`, you should register the filter like this:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p
            .path("/get")
            .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
            .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
        .build();
}
```

you could not using `application.yaml` or `application.properties` to config the custom gateway filter. If you want to config in `application.yaml` or `application.properties`, you need to implements `GatewayFilterFactory`.